# JqueryUI slider: After dragging it still "jumps" one step

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The slider can and should be changed by:
dragging,
clicking,
entering a number and by 
pressing +/-.

Works all fine, except the dragging: When I release the handle it "jumps" one more step into the dragging direction. If, for example I drag from 1500 to 2000 it will stop at 2010 on release. If I take out the `change: refreshCalculation` it does not do that, but then of course it would not allow +/- and manual number insertion.

Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/YvsmT/

```
$("#slider-vertical").slider({
orientation: "horizontal",
range: "min",
animate: 500,
min: 0,
max: 8760,
value: 1500,
step: 10,
slide: refreshCalculation,
change: refreshCalculation
});

function refreshCalculation() {
var s4 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
$("#betriebsstunden").val(s4);
}

$("#plus1").click(function () {
var bs1 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
$("#slider-vertical").slider("value", bs1 + 10);
refreshCalculation();
});

$("#minus1").click(function () {
var bs1 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
$("#slider-vertical").slider("value", bs1 - 10);
refreshCalculation();
});

$("#betriebsstunden").change(function () {
var value = this.value;
$("#slider-vertical").slider("value", value);
});


refreshCalculation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `change: refreshCalculation` And it's working fine.

```
$("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    animate: 500,
    min: 0,
    max: 8760,
    value: 1500,
    step: 10,
    //change: refreshCalculation,
    slide: refreshCalculation
});

function refreshCalculation() {
    var s4 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
    $("#betriebsstunden").val(s4);
}

$("#plus1").click(function () {
    var bs1 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
    $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", bs1 + 10);
    refreshCalculation();
});

$("#minus1").click(function () {
    var bs1 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
    $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", bs1 - 10);
    refreshCalculation();
});

$("#betriebsstunden").change(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", value);
});


refreshCalculation();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YvsmT/1/

Comment: Yea, I wrote that already during my initial post. I figured it out by now. I think I used the slide parameter incorrectly. I adjusted it accordingly to the jQueryUI documentation and it works fine now.

Comment: @user2164882 ok no problem.